# Ajax not performing update when i deploy my web app to the server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, asmx

I have a web method in an `.asmx` web service, I am calling this method via jQuery ajax, to update database record; its working perfectly on my local machine during debugging, the issue is that when I publish it to the server, it no longer works. Surprisingly other updates in different pages are working just fine, please tell me where I'm getting it wrong.

Below is my code

jQuery ajax function

```
 function Updateaction() {
        $('#updateinit').click(function () {

            $('#iniativemodal').modal('show');
            debugger
          var Id=  $('#ikipitxt').val();
          var name=  $('#namtxt').val();
          var initd = $('#initdate').val();
           var des= $('#descrtxt').val();
           var budget= $('#budgettxt').val();
           var dur= $('#durationtxt').val();
           var inter= $('#intervalstarttxt').val();
           var ends =$('#intervalendtxt').val();
           var pers= $('#persontxt').val();
            var kpi=$('#ikpitxt').val();

            $.ajax({

                url:"/MyService.asmx/editActionplan?Id=" + $('#ikipitxt').val() + "&name=" + $('#namtxt').val() + "&initdate=" + $('#initdate').val() + "&Description=" + $('#descrtxt').val() + "&budget=" + $('#budgettxt').val() + "&duration=" + $('#durationtxt').val() + "&intervalstart=" + $('#intervalstarttxt').val() + "  &intervalend=" + $('#intervalendtxt').val() + "&responseperson=" + $('#persontxt').val() + "&kpi=" + $('#ikipitxt').val() + "",

                data: '{Id: ' + Id + ', name: "' + name + '",initdate: "' + initd + '",Description:"' + des + '", budget: "' + budget + '",duration: "' + dur + '",intervalstart: "' + inter + '",intervalend: "' + ends + '",responseperson: "' + pers + '",kpi: "' + kpi + '"}',

                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    $('#iniativemodal').modal('hide');

                    $('#ikipitxt').val("");
                    $('#namtxt').val("");
                    $('#initdate').val("");
                    $('#descrtxt').val("");
                    $('#budgettxt').val("");
                    $('#durationtxt').val("");
                    $('#intervalstarttxt').val("");
                    $('#intervalendtxt').val("");
                    $('#persontxt').val("");
                    $('#ikpitxt').val("");
                    displayAction();

                },

                error: function (errormessage) {

                    alert(errormessage.responseText);

                }

            });
        });


    }
```

Webmethod in the webservice

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void editActionplan(int Id, string name,string initdate, string Description, string budget, string duration,string intervalstart,string intervalend,string responseperson,int kpi)
    {

        string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            //this what you looking for
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" UPDATE Iniative SET name=@name,initdate=@initdate,Description=@Description,budget=@budget,duration=@duration,intervalstart=@intervalstart,intervalend=@intervalend,responseperson=@responseperson,kpi=@kpi  WHERE Id=@Id", conn))
            {



                try
                {
                    conn.Open();


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@initdate", initdate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@budget", budget);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duration", duration);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intervalstart", intervalstart);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intervalend", intervalend);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@responseperson", responseperson);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kpi", kpi);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please give more information than simply 'it doesn't work'. The first attempt to debug should be to check the console for errors, and also to see what the response from the AJAX request is.  Hopefully this gives you something to diagnose

Comment: This is where you are going wrong: `catch (Exception) { }` - you are *ignoring* any errors in the command.  Maybe you don't have write access / maybe the table definition is wrong - that's what it will be telling you in that Exception.

Comment: if its working on your local ,probably there might be a difference between your local db and your server db. check db columns and their types , check if your web services is even deployed on server. try writing some logs ,

Comment: @freedomn-m, i had previus put an alert inside the success of the ajax, and its executing through, note that, i have a function that updates another table in the same db and its working just fine on the server, what is not happening is executing the correct thing from the webmethod

Comment: @umer the database is exactly the same, and i have other methods to update that is actually updating, also in the same table, the insert is doing just fine

Comment: @Timothy , you should write some logs , use Log4net for writing some logs on server side

Comment: @umer this is the error im gettingconversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: @freedomn-m conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Well, there's your answer - nothing to do with the transport mechanism (jquery/ajax/asmx) and all to do with your table/environment definitions across different environments (eg your release server may be set to a different locale from your local server) - use ANSI dates (yyyy-mm-dd) not locale dates.

Comment: you can set some settings in your Global.asax.cs file. what is the datetime format of the string you trying to save into db ?  you need to set that culture in your global.asax.cs file

Comment: i have added a sample settings in the answer below , you can set your settings according to your date time string

Comment: @umer thanks a lot its now woeking it was that i just needed to convert the json date string to date

Comment: @Timothy then how come it was working on your local environment ?

Comment: @umer im as just as amazed as you, but now its working

Answer (score 0):

inside your global.asax.cs file add the below code

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern= "HH:mm:ss"; //your time format

        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy"; // your date format 
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;




    }
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intervalstart", Convert.ToDateTime(item.intervalstart));